# Is there a way to find a certain letter in a variable with discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am new to making discord bots and I am using `discord.js`, I was wondering if there is a way to search a variable for a certain letter.

**Example Code:**

```js
const word = "apple"
if (word.contains("a") return message.channel.send("variable contains a")
```

**Output:** variable that contains `a`

Comment: Did you try ```word.indexOf('a')``` ? see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you meant [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes):

```js
if (word.includes("a") {
    return message.channel.send("variable contains a");
}
```